# jQuery.offset() on <body> element provides incorrect "top" value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

FIDDLE IS [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/SCGdZ/2/) (logs to console)

The situation is when the page starts out with a `<H1>` that has a margin-top greater than the margin found on `<body>`.

This causes the `<body>` to be pushed lower in the page yet `$('body').offset().top` remains set to the `<body>`'s margin-top. This of course causes my debug element (which highlights the position of elements) to be incorrect since the body's dummy element is now in the wrong position.

Curiously the rest of the `$(elem).offset()` values are correct for any descendant of `<body>`.

Is there a fix for this short of manually checking the margin-top of the recursively first childs of body with a while loop?

Noticing the issue on Safari 6 though I suspect I'll find it on Chrome as well.

Comment: Can you simply change the margin-top of `body` to match its children?

Comment: Why would the margin-top on the H1 effect the offset position of the body? I see that Google highlights the body tag as just the header tag, but that appears to be a rendering issue on Chromes developer.

Comment: @BoltClock probably. I'm working on a general purpose JS library, not a specific page. So my code is intended to be very flexible.

Comment: @Tom because the height reported by `$('body').outerHeight` (and `height()` and `innerHeight()`) is the height of the body which does **NOT** include the H1's margin-top.

Comment: Not really a solution, but from jQuery: Note: jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the body element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery 1.9.0 has addressed this issue. Thanks so much, jQuery is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

It might work to use the offset plus the difference of the height of the `html` element minus the `body` element.

console.log("body.offset().top = "+ ($('html').offset().top + $('html').height() - $('body').height()));

---

Update: This solution will only work if there is not a margin-bottom on the page.

You could additionally add a clear div at the bottom of the page.

`$('body').append("<div style=\"clear: all;\">&nbsp;</div>");`

Note that the div must have content to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/SCGdZ/7/

Comment: I think this is a solid work around. I'm not actually going to put this chunk of jQuery into an inner animation loop just to get the correct values for a single specific element in isolated circumstances but it is good to know I can avoid a dom traversal loop.

Comment: This answer wont work if the bottom of the page has a margin-bottom.

Comment: Couldn't we extend it using similar logic to account for that?

Comment: I posted additional information in the answer. If you append `$('body').append("<div style=\"clear: all;\">&nbsp;</div>");`, the body element will extend it's height to include the last margin.

Answer (score 1):

I found a John Resig post about how fast and awesome `getBoundingClientRect` is [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/)... I wonder why it is not used for jQuery's `offset()`!

I shall use this method instead and hopefully it will not suffer from this same issue.

Update: Looks good! (the non integer top value is due to the  somehow having style `-webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;`)

You can see that the body has margin=8

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately apparently Mobile Safari does not provide this function. Which is a bit of a bummer.

Answer (score 0):

[Find Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SCGdZ/5/)

`a[0].style.marginTop` it remains uninitialized even after declaring it in css that's why it was returning nothing.

Therefore we must take care of initializing `a[0].style.marginTop`

Comment: Thanks, this definitely contributes to the discussion but it does not address the fact that body's offset value provided is still not taking into account the margin-top of the leading `<h1>`. See the revision 6 of the fiddle. Output says 8px when it should be 20px.

Comment: Even I can't understand this absurd behavior, when we set a[0].style.marginTop greater than CSS it readily shows the effect, while if we keep a[0].style.marginTop less than that of CSS it fails to show effect.